# Shortcut for bullets/numbered formatting in Powerpoint for Mac

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

The [shortcuts page in the PowerPoint docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-PowerPoint-2016-for-Mac-f25f92b3-b0a8-4c60-aec8-954b72aa81ad) does not mention any shortcuts for formatting a paragraph as bullets/numbered - and how to then reset a paragraph back to normal/un-bulletted.

I am guessing such shortcuts *do* exist .. does anyone happen to know them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **PowerPoint** brings up a dialog showing several options, it seems the best that can be done is to create a custom shortcut to the dialog then select the desired formatting.

---

### To create a custom keyboard shortcut for PowerPoint:

Open the **System Preferences** either by searching Spotlight, clicking the  Menu, selecting from the dock or your favorite method of getting to it.

- Select **Keyboard** in the settings (Typically on the second row of icons)
- Select the **Shortcuts** tab
- Select **App Shortcuts** from the list on the left
- Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button at the bottom
- Change the **Applicaton:** to **Microsoft PowerPoint.app** using the dropdown
- type *EXACTLY* as the command appears in PowerPoint's Format Menu. In this case `Bullets and Numbering…` ← Note that is *not* 3 dots but an ellipsis.  Type <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> or use the **Character Viewer** if needed to get it.
- In the Keyboard Shortcut input type the desired shortcut.  As an example: <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

Now, back in PowerPoint select the paragraph and evoke the dialog with the shortcut.  Unfortunately, Microsoft does not allow (that I can find) keyboard navigation of this dialog to select the desired bullet style so one will have to use the mouse at this point.
**EDIT:** Note that one can change *Full Keyboard Access* in the **Keyboard** settings.  Changing to **All Controls** *may* allow navigating using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key in the bullets dialog box.

See illustration below.

---

[image: Keyboard shortcut settings]

[image: Shortcut added]

Comment: Ouch .. resorting to a custom shortcut.. and then we *still* need to use the mouse..  Well i'll upvote for your effort to have explained this, but will still hold out a bit for any alternative.  If none found then eventually will award here.. for being (unfortunately)  the correct answer

Comment: Yup, I hear you. You can thank Microsoft for that.  Perhaps send them some product feedback.  See my update on the change to Full Keyboard Access to try to manipulate the dialog box with the tab key.

Comment: `Full Keyboard Access` does actually work .. but it is a *lot* of tabbing .. which makes it of dubious value.

Comment: I know what you mean.  I prefer personally to use Keynote but it would be nice if developers like Apple and Microsoft made their apps a bit more keyboard friendly.  At least custom shortcuts can be made for all menu items.  Hope you find a solution that fits your workflow.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually this works better than anticipated: after changing to single shortcut then there are only three more keystrokes required - 2 or 3 tabs and then enter. Oh btw no need for `Character Viewer`: **you** already did that. I just cut and paste from *your* answer above.

Comment: On US keyboards you can use `option`+`;` to type ellipsis. It might be similar on other layouts.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

It's clunky, but it works and it fits the hand surprisingly well.

Works in PowerPoint 2019 as well.

Comment: Hi - i'd like to understand what you're suggesting.  What do you mean by `Alt` ? I'm on Macos.  What is 'H' (is that help ?)  I can't get off the ground on this suggestion.  Please describe each of those keystrokes in turn: is it Alt of is it Option or is it something else. Do we first hit H then U etc.

Comment: Try option on a Mac? If that doesn't work I'm not sure. But the other keys are what they are. It's just an H. Between G and J.

Comment: While `Alt` is typically understood as `Option` on mac I did try the above and it completely does not work at all. Are you actually _using_ a mac ?